# PhpDOC syntax for related table

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, phpdoc

PHPStorm complains about a property accessed via magic method, because I didn't set the related comment:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Model\Entity\ItemOrder;
use Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;
use Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface;
use Cake\Http\Response;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;

/**
 * Items Controller
 *
 * @property ItemsTable $Items
 *
 * @method Item[]|ResultSetInterface paginate($object = null, array $settings = [])
 */
class ItemOrdersController extends AppController
{
    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return Response|void
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Orders', 'ItemOrdersTypes', 'Products', 'ItemOrdersStates', 'Proformas', 'DeliveryNotes', 'Invoices']
        ];
        $itemOrders = $this->paginate($this->Items);

        $this->set(compact('itemOrders'));
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     * @param string $id Item id.
     * @return Response|null Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add($id)
    {
        $itemOrder = $this->ItemOrders->newEntity();  // <--- this one
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the right syntax to declare such a property.
I tried with

```
* @property ItemOrders $ItemOrders
```

and

```
* @property ItemOrdersTable $ItemOrders
```

and

```
* @property object $ItemOrders
```

but without luck.
I also checked the docs for [property](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html) and [type](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html) without finding nothing useful.

Comment: What type is it? `ItemsTable`, `ItemOrders` or `object`? Is the class within the `App\Controller` namespace?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried with both (fixed the question). `ItemOrders` is the table `ItemOrdersTable`. In the file `ItemOrdersTable.php` the namespace is `namespace App\Model\Table;`

Comment: So they problem is not the syntax (it is `@property type variable` anyway) but, instead, that you don't know what type it is. What does `debug($this->Items);` show?

Comment: I'm afraid this should be another question: even if I added `Configure::write('debug', 2);` neither `debug()` nor `var_dump()` show nothing.

Comment: As said the previous comment also var_dump() prints nothing. I'm going to open a new question for this. I'm new to Cakephp and surely I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, found it. `ItemsTable` was left there by mistake (old code) and can be removed. Instead, `debug($this->ItemOrders)` (the variable that causes the warning) outputs `object(App\Model\Table\ItemOrdersTable)`.